# A nested loop that adds numbers from the sequence in pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list:

`the_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Next I would like to sum pairs of numbers from the list, next pairs in the next step, and so on, until we get only one number at the end. The next steps would look like this:

```
 [3, 5, 7, 9]
 [8, 12, 16]
 [20, 28]
 [48]
```

I use a loop to add pairs:

```
the_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in range(len(the_list) - 1):
    a, b = the_list[i], the_list[i + 1]
    c = a + b
    print (c)
```

What gives:

```
3
5
7
9
```

But I do not know how to loop it to the next steps. Because, for now, only a very bad idea of adding to the new list comes to mind, which would be a completely wrong idea with a large starting list. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `zip` the list against itself offset by one index, then sum consecutive elements until the list collapses into a slngle value

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
while len(l) > 1:
    l = [i+j for i,j in zip(l, l[1:])]
    print(l)
```

Output

```
[3, 5, 7, 9]
[8, 12, 16]
[20, 28]
[48]
```

Comment: You don't need `[:]` either, just `l` for that one [(although `l` isn't the greatest variable name)](http://pep8.org/#names-to-avoid)

Answer (score 3):

Just loop through and add 2 elements at a time:

```
the_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

while len(the_list) > 1:
    the_list = [the_list[i] + the_list[i+1] for i in range(len(the_list)-1)]
    print(the_list)
```

Output:

```
[3, 5, 7, 9]
[8, 12, 16]
[20, 28]
[48]
```

**EDIT** I would recommend @CoryKramer's answer, it performs better than this one:

```
In [1]: def get_to_one(arr):
   ...:     while len(arr) > 1:
   ...:         arr = [arr[i] + arr[i+1] for i in range(len(arr)-1)]
   ...:     return arr
   ...:
   ...: def kramer_solution(l):
   ...:     while len(l) > 1:
   ...:         l = [i + j for i, j in zip(l, l[1:])]
   ...:     return l
   ...:

In [2]: %timeit get_to_one(range(100))
1.01 ms ± 2.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit kramer_solution(range(100))
646 µs ± 1.34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit get_to_one(range(200))
3.81 ms ± 14.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit kramer_solution(range(200))
2.45 ms ± 19.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: IMO CoryKramer's answer is cleaner than mine, and I would recommend using that one.

Answer (score 3):

Another variant with `map()`:

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> the_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> while len(the_list) > 1:
...     the_list = list(map(add, the_list, the_list[1:]))
...     print(the_list)
... 
[3, 5, 7, 9]
[8, 12, 16]
[20, 28]
[48]
```

Comment: Very clean! Nice!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use recursion:

```
the_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
def pairs(current):
   d = [current[i]+current[i+1] for i in range(len(current)-1)]
   yield d
   if len(d) > 1:
      yield from pairs(d)

print(list(pairs(the_list)))
```

Output:

```
[[3, 5, 7, 9], [8, 12, 16], [20, 28], [48]]
```

Comment: interesting solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works:

```
while len(the_list) > 1:
    the_list = [the_list[i]+the_list[i+1] for i in range(len(the_list)-1)]
```

I am sure there exists a better way to do this. Ultimately, your loop was only ever going to go through list a single time because `for i in range(len(the_list)-1)` terminates once `i = len(the_list)-2` (`range` provides values one less than the given argument ).

To my knowledge, the garbage collector will take care of the leftover list after reassigning the variable name `the_list` to a new list -- however, if you're worried about generating a new list each iteration in the `while` loop there is this:

```
while len(the_list) > 1:
    for i in range(len(the_list)-1):
        a, b = the_list[i], the_list[i + 1]
        c = a + b
        the_list[i] = c
    the_list.pop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another fancy solution with recursion and higher-order functions.

```
def foo(the_list):
  if len(the_list) == 1:
    return the_list
  number_pairs = list(zip(the_list[0::1], the_list[1::1]))
  return foo(list(map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1], number_pairs)))

the_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(foo(the_list))
```